# mongoose don't create 2dsphere index in mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am not able to create **2dsphere** **index** in **MongoDB atlas**. I already created in my localhost MongoDB. But I don't know why it wont created in **Anastasia MongoDB**?

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const schema = new Schema(
  {
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true
      },
    }
  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: "createdAt" } },
);

schema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });
schema.index({ "location.coordinates": "2d" });

const Apartment = mongoose.model("Apartment", schema,);

export default Apartment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve the problem by downgrade mongoose to ver 5.3.6